# Async read large file results in blocks of null reads on iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsinputstream

This has me stumped. I'm trying to read a 6MB CSV file on iOS line by line. I've tried using plain C file pointers and NSInputStream polling but settled on the following which felt the cleanest. All three approaches result in what seems like a random block of reads returning success but fill the buffer with all null bytes. I say "random" but it has consistency. The reads stop working at the exact same point when re-running the program, and the number of reads is suspicious (more on that below).

```
- (id)initWithFileAtPath:(NSString *)path {
   if ((self = [super init])) {
      filePath = [path copy];
      queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
      queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
      buffer = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
      bytes = malloc(CHUNK_SIZE * sizeof(UTF8Char));
   }

   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
   [filePath release];
   [queue release];
   [buffer release];
   free(bytes);
   [super dealloc];
}

- (void)stream:(NSInputStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
   switch (eventCode) {
      case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
         break;
      case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
         [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self readChunk: stream];
            [self drainBuffer];
         }];
         break;
      case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
         if ([buffer length] > 0) {
            [delegate reader:self didReadLine:[NSString stringWithString:buffer]];
            [buffer setString:@""];
         }

         [stream close];
         [stream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                           forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

         [stream release];

         [delegate readerDidFinishReading:self];

         break;
      default:
         NSLog(@"StreamReader: event %d", eventCode);
         break;
   }
}

- (void)enumerateLines {
   NSInputStream *stream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:filePath];
   stream.delegate = self;

   [stream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                     forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

   [stream open];
}

- (void)readChunk: (NSInputStream*)stream {
   NSInteger readSize = [stream read:bytes maxLength:CHUNK_SIZE];
   if (readSize) {
      if (bytes[0] == '\0') {
         NSLog(@"null buffer %d", readSize);
      }
      NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes
                                                  length:readSize
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      [buffer appendString:string];
      [string release];
   } else {
      NSLog(@"StreamReader: read zero bytes");
   }
}

- (void)drainBuffer {
   static NSCharacterSet *newlines = nil;
   if (newlines == nil) {
      newlines = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
   }

   NSRange newlinePos;
   while ((newlinePos = [buffer rangeOfCharacterFromSet:newlines]).location != NSNotFound) {
      NSString *line = [buffer substringToIndex:newlinePos.location];

      // remove the line from the buffer along with line separator
      [buffer deleteCharactersInRange: (NSRange){0, [line length]}];
      while ([buffer length] > 0 && [newlines characterIsMember:[buffer characterAtIndex:0]]) {
         [buffer deleteCharactersInRange:(NSRange){0, 1}];
      }

      [delegate reader:self didReadLine: line];
   }
}
```

While reading the 6MB file, twice I will get a series of 96 "bad reads" when CHUNK_SIZE is 1024. If CHUNK_SIZE is 512 there will be a series of 192 "bad reads". What do I mean by "bad reads"? The NSInputStream read message returns success, and no error event occurs in the delegate callback. Yet the `bytes` buffer has all null values.

- iOS 7.0.4, iPad 2
- does NOT happen on desktop
- does NOT happen in simulator
- decreasing file size to aprox. 1MB "fixes" the problem on the iPad

It's most likely worth noting that I instantiate the reader class while on the main UI thread.

So... am I doing something subtly (or not subtly) wrong here? Or have I uncovered some sort of obscure iOS bug?

Comment: I'd add oodles of NSLog statements, and plod through them trying to find my bug. The odds of the file system having serious problems at this point are extremely remote.

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is you are reading random chunks of a UTF8 stream, then assuming that what you get back is coherent. If you get a chunk of string that "breaks" in the middle of a UTF8 encoding, its going to cause a slew of problems. If you want to do partial strings construction your algorithm is going to need rework to prevent this - its not a trivial thing to do.

Comment: To eliminate that as a culprit for this problem I converted the file to ascii removing any non-convertalbe characters with `iconv -f utf8 -t ascii -c myfile.csv >clean.csv`. The behavior I describe in my post is while using a file with ascii characters.

Comment: Why are you using a NSOperation queue and not just a serial dispatch queue? NSOperation queues allow multiple operations to occur. Your current solution just seems odd. Anyway, as a last suggestion, put the file on a public site like Dropbox, spin up a simple demo app that just downloads (but has the problem on an iPad), and I will look at it (maybe someone else will too). It pays to build up points on this site as a 50 or 100 pt bouncy will go a long way to motivating people. I only have an iPad 3 so it may or may not work out of the box.